# Creating custom grok filters

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I need to find grok pattern for files where the lines are of the format :

```
 3 dbm.kfa            0        340220       7766754          93.9
 3 swapper/3            0        340220       7766754          93.9
```

This is the grok pattern that I have done so far.

```
\s*%{INT:no1}\s*%{USERNAME:name}\s*%{INT:no2}\s*%{INT:no3}\s*%{INT:no4}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:ans}
```

The field `USERNAME` works for `dbm.kfa` but not for `swapper/3` as `USERNAME` does not include `\` character. I would like to create some custom filter for this purpose, but have no idea how to create one.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom pattern you need to use an external file in the following format and put that file in a directory the will be used only for pattern files.

```
PATTERN_NAME [regex for your pattern]
```

Then you will need to change your grok config to point to the pattern files directory.

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/path/to/patterns/dir"]
    match => { "message" => "%{PATTERN_NAME:fieldName}" } 
}
```

But in your specific case if you change `%{USERNAME:name}` to `%{DATA:name}` it should work.

For a better explanation about the custom patterns you should read [this part of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns).

You also can find all the core `grok` patterns that ships with logstash in this [github repository](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns), the most used are in the [`grok-patterns`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) file.